# Auto fill value multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays

Question might be difficult to answer but here it goes:-
See I have an market order book in array like this:-

```
$str = array(
array(
    'amount' => 1.5,
    'price' => 10,
    'user' => 'test',
    'filled' => 0,
    'status' => 'active',
),
array(
    'amount' => 2.5,
    'price' => 10,
    'user' => 'test1',
    'filled' => 0,
    'status' => 'active',
),
array(
    'amount' => 5,
    'price' =>10,
    'user' => 'test2',
    'filled' => 0,
    'status' => 'active',
),
array(
    'amount' => 10,
    'price' => 10,
    'user' => 'test3',
    'filled' => 0,
    'status' => 'active',
)
);
```

Here the above arrays shows the name of user selling the amount of a thing and the price per thing. Status is active as nothing is still sold to anyone(filled is 0). Let's say a user named test4 comes into the picture and wants to buy 6 things at price'10'. How do I make so that the first three orders get dynamically filled and also from 'active' status to 'done' or 'partially filled'.

Please help :)

Comment: Dear Jeff I wanted to help you but found this question as too broad, also you didn't share any effort. Please share if you have any ?

Comment: Hmm see its just about updating order book with auto fill. Lets say one user is ready to sell 10 of product and other 5 and one comes to buy 12. I want the 1st one to sell his whole and get updated'filled' as 10 and the other to get updated 'filled' as 2 with his 'status' partially active. I don't know where to start from..